# Make works fine, but the result does not run. What now?

Tags: gcc, c, make, gdb

I am trying to run https://github.com/seanpringle/simpleswitcher on my ubuntu 12.04

I downloaded it and compiled it. However, when I run I get

```
*** glibc detected *** ./simpleswitcher: free(): invalid next size (fast): 0x08bff5a8 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x75ee2)[0x185ee2]
./simpleswitcher[0x8049a97]
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf3)[0x1294d3]
./simpleswitcher[0x8049d1d]
======= Memory map: ========
00110000-002b3000 r-xp 00000000 08:04 424359     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc-2.15.so
(memory map goes on and on)
```

how can I figure out what is going on ?
what are some hypotesis I should consider ? How do I start trying to figure this out ?

I am a programmer -to say, I can write simple C and python- but I frankly have no idea what is going on

Comment: Try from this branch/fork https://github.com/DaveDavenport/simpleswitcher , I looked at the pull reuests and one had a "fixed ubuntu build" commit, might be worth a shot

Comment: well, what do you know ... It works.

I though I needed to learn gdb today. Apparently, I needed git =P

Comment: cool. I am still curious about how I would debug the program, so I am not closing the question yet.

But yes. Make it an answer so that I can give you an upvote

Comment: Some others might know more about tracing errors, a paste of the full error may help on http://paste.ubuntu.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In looking at the "Issues" or "Pull Requests" one of the pull requests labeled "small updates" has a commit that says:

```
Martijn Koedam        Fix building ubuntu          6d0f4a9
```

But in the comment section of that pull, It looks like the author decided to "Cherry Pick" only part of the commits, excluding some Distribution specific changes saying:

> Some simpleswitcher users run limited versions of make (eg, bmake)
>   which the current crude Makefile supports.

This leads me to believe that it might work on Ubuntu with this commit (commit was about 4 months ago).

So try building with this fork, as it looks like they are targeting some distribution specific issues: https://github.com/DaveDavenport/simpleswitcher

Comment: I figured it out!

It was just a malloc error.

Thanks for the initial push